# Moq setup returns null object when the method is called by a UnitTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, moq, xunit

**Test Setup**

> Mock gives null object when the test hits the method inside the controller

My controller's constructor has two dependencies which I mocked.  While running the test for CheckOut it is giving null object in the result. I am using AutoMapper to map between Model objects and Business

```
[Fact]
public void CheckOutSomethingsTest()
{
    Mock<ICheckoutService> checkoutServiceMock = new Mock<ICheckoutService>();
    Mock<IMapper> mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();

    checkoutServiceMock.Setup(c => c.CheckoutSomethings(new CheckOutSomethingsInput
    {
        SecretKey = "SecureKey",
        UserId = 100,
        SomethingIds = new List<int> { 10001, 1002, 1003 }
    }))
    .Returns<List<CheckedOutSomething>>((o) => new List<CheckedOutSomething>
    {
            new CheckedOutSomething { Id = 10001, Remarks = "Success" },
            new CheckedOutSomething  { Id = 10002, Remarks = "Success" }
    });

    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddSomething(new AutoMapperBusinessToEntitiesSomething());
        cfg.AddSomething(new AutoMapperModelsToBusinessSomething());
    });

    var mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
    var controller = new SomethingsController(checkoutServiceMock.Object, mapper);

    var result = controller.CheckOut(
        new CheckOutSomethingInputModel 
        { 
              UserId = 100, 
              SomethingIds = new List<int> { 10001, 10002, 10003 } 
        });

    Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result.Result);
    Assert.Equal(2, result.Value.Count);
}
```

> Service
>   **Constructor**

```
public ProfilesController(ICheckoutService checkoutService, IMapper mapper)
{
    this.checkoutService = checkoutService;
    this.mapper = mapper;            
}
```

**Method**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("checkout")]
public ActionResult<List<CheckedOutSomethingModel>> 
        CheckOut([FromBody] CheckOutSomethingInputModel checkoutInput)
{       
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    } 

    var input = mapper.Map<CheckOutSomethingsInput>(checkoutInput);
    var output = mapper.Map<List<CheckedOutSomethingModel>> 
    (checkoutService.CheckoutSomethings(input));
    return Ok(output);
}
```

> I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong

Comment: You configured mocks to return given object only when certain instance of `CheckOutSomethingsInput` is provided as argument. Because `CheckOutSomethingsInput` instance provided in production code during runtime will be different instance than configured one, mock will treat method call as not configured and will return default value of return type.

Comment: @Fa checkoutServiceMock.Setup(c => c.CheckoutProfiles(It.IsAny<CheckOutProfilesInput>()))
                .Returns(new List<CheckedOutProfile>
            {
                new CheckedOutProfile { Id = 10001, Remarks = "Success" },
                new CheckedOutProfile  { Id = 10002, Remarks = "Success" }
            });
Is it like this

Comment: That is one way. You maybe want to have another test to check that expected values are passed.

Answer (score 0):

@Fabio Many Thanks Is it like this

```
checkoutServiceMock.Setup(c => c.CheckoutSomethings(It.IsAny<CheckOutSomethingsInput>()))
                .Returns(new List<CheckedOutSomething>
            {
                new CheckedOutSomething { Id = 10001, Remarks = "Success" },
                new CheckedOutSomething { Id = 10002, Remarks = "Success" }
            });
```

I actually did and It worked, Thanks Again